# Understanding code generated by MicrocontrollerEmbedCode

Tags: control-systems, code-generation, microcontroller-kit

I've been using [MicrocontrollerKit](https://www.wolfram.com/language/12/microcontroller-kit/?product=mathematica) for a while now to generate code for little projects, inverse pendulums, filters, etc. Generally it works well.

I am now currently trying to design a [LQI](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/265706415_Design_of_continuous_and_discrete_LQI_control_systems_with_stable_inner_loops) (Linear quadratic integrator) Or atleast *trying* to understand them and test on an already working system with a steady state error.

The design and simulation seems to work well, so now it comes to generating the code and trying it out.

```
lineargains = {26.8592, 2.85176, -0.0189932};
controlforce = -lineargains.{\[Theta][t] - \[Pi], \[Theta]'[t], \[Phi]'[t]};


integrator = TransferFunctionModel[ki/z, z]
ssm = NonlinearStateSpaceModel[{{}, {controlforce}}, {}, {\[Theta][t], \[Theta]'[t], \[Phi]'[t]}]

lqid = SystemsConnectionsModel[{ToDiscreteTimeModel[integrator /. ki -> 56, 0.001], ToDiscreteTimeModel[ssm, 0.001]}, {{1, 1} -> {2, 1}}, {{1, 1}, {2,2}, {2, 3}}, {2, 1}] // SystemsModelMerge


\[ScriptCapitalM]1 = MicrocontrollerEmbedCode[lqid, <|"Target" -> "ArduinoUno", "Inputs" -> {"A0" -> "Analog", "A1" -> "Analog", "A2" -> "Analog"},"Outputs" -> {"Serial"}|>, <|"ConnectionPort" -> None|>, <|"Language" -> "Wiring"|>]

\[ScriptCapitalM]1["SourceCode"]
```

At this point, I believe anyways, I have properly set up the system I want.

What I don't understand, is the generated Wiring code and how it applies to the discrete LQI controller. Here is a snippet to the relevant parts, and a [pastebin for the full codes.](https://pastebin.com/WCsMeFsJ)

```
double u[3] = {0, 0, 0};
double y[1] = {84.38063590995105};
void update_nssm(double *u, double *y)
{
static double x[1] = {0};
double x1[1];
y[0] = 84.38063590995105 - 0.22561720114594416*x[0] - 0.11280860057297208*u[0] - 2.8517595773639597*u[1] + 0.018993162921974713*u[2];
x1[0] = x[0] + u[0];
x[0] = x1[0];
}
void loop()
{
double uu0 = read_adc(0);
double uu1 = read_adc(1);
double uu2 = read_adc(2);
u[0] = uu0;
u[1] = uu1;
u[2] = uu2;
update_nssm(u, y);
Serial.write(19);
Serial.print(y[0], 2);
Serial.write(17);
delay(1);
}
```

There is a mysterious ~84 within the code for `y[1]` that is generated and never called...and within `update_nssm()` the state-space controller itself an 84 that I can't imagine would ever result in a value that makes sense. (the controller should create a signal that would be between -2 and 2 to control the system.

This also never appears when generating the code for the more simple LQR controller.

As seen here:

```
\[ScriptCapitalM] = MicrocontrollerEmbedCode[ToDiscreteTimeModel[ssm, 0.001], <|"Target" -> "ArduinoUno", "Inputs" -> {"A0" -> "Analog", "A1" -> "Analog", "A2" -> "Analog"},"Outputs" -> {"Serial"}|>, <|"ConnectionPort" -> None|>, <|"Language" -> "Wiring"|>]\[ScriptCapitalM]["SourceCode"]
```

And the it's code:

```
void update_nssm(double *u, double *y)
{
y[0] = -26.8591906126124*(-M_PI + u[0]) - 2.8517595773639597*u[1] + 0.018993162921974713*u[2];
}
```

When comparing to the two, one could assume that the 84~ should be some kind of subtraction from $\pi$...however thus far, I have never seem Mathematica output $\pi$ in anything but radians, as such I can't understand if the generated code is anything but correct, or how this code is generated from the given `lqid` [`StateSpaceModel`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/StateSpaceModel.html).

In the simpler `LQR` case, I can directly read and understand what was generated ([and have used successfully](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Lzw3ZGTuMUU)), however in the `lqid` this doesn't seem to add up.

How is [MicrocontrollerEmbedCode](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/MicrocontrollerKit/ref/MicrocontrollerEmbedCode.html) generating this code?

I fully admit I may be the one making the mistakes here...in which case, what would be the proper way to generate such a controller?

Comment: Happy to learn that the [`MicrocontrollerKit`](https://www.wolfram.com/microcontroller-kit/) is useful to you. Thanks for the feedback.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The value `84.38063590995105=-26.8592*π` is a residue that pops up if the equilibrium value is not set correctly.

There are a few things that need to be changed to straighten things out.

You need to specify `ssm` with the correct equilibrium value of $\pi$ for $\theta$.

```
ssm = NonlinearStateSpaceModel[{{}, {controlforce}}, {}, {{θ[t], N@π}, θ'[t], ϕ'[t]}]
```

That way when $\theta$ is $\pi$, `controlforce` is `0`.

(The `N@π` is needed due to a bug that fails to generate the correct code for `π`.)

Next, if you use [`SystemsModelMerge`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/SystemsModelMerge.html) to merge the connections the equilibrium value gets blown away. [`SystemsModelMerge`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/SystemsModelMerge.html) can preserve the equilibrium values of states and the net inputs and outputs, but equilibrium values in any intermediate connections is lost in the merge.

To prevent that you need to keep it in the unreduced state.

```
lqid = SystemsConnectionsModel[{ToDiscreteTimeModel[integrator /. ki -> 56, 0.001], 
   ToDiscreteTimeModel[ssm, 0.001]}, {{1, 1} -> {2, 1}}, {{1, 1}, {2,2}, {2, 3}}, {2, 1}];
```

With these changes the relevant generated code will be as follows and when `u[0]`(which is `u_1[0]`) is `π`, `y[0]` will also be `0`.

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the quick answer and solution, The solution works and i will try the generated code on the real thing when i get the chance!